# How to migrate user's data from Cordova app to native Swift app?

Tags: swift, cordova, migration, phonegap

So we have an app that's built with Cordova PhoneGap already on the app store, And we are building a native version of the app.
But we need to keep some of the user's data already cached from the older Cross-Platform app and read it from Swift.

The Cross platform app uses UIWebView's localStorage to cache this data, so is there a way to read that data from a new swift app?